# Creating view in SQL Server and it's giving me a message

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this view:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT  
    Updates.FileInfo.FileInfoId, Updates.FileInfo.Filename, 
    Updates.FileInfo.FileDate, Updates.FileInfo.FileSize, 
    Updates.FileInfo.FileBlob, Updates.FileInfo.DownloadId, 
    Updates.Download.UploaderName, Updates.Download.ExpireDate, 
    Updates.Download.UploadDate, Updates.Download.SoftwareTypeId, 
    Updates.Download.IsActive, Updates.SoftwareType.Name
FROM
    Updates.Download 
INNER JOIN
    Updates.SoftwareType ON Updates.Download.SoftwareTypeId = Updates.SoftwareType.SoftwareTypeId 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    Updates.FileInfo ON Updates.Download.DownloadId = Updates.FileInfo.DownloadId
WHERE
    (Updates.Download.SoftwareTypeId = 7) 
    AND (Updates.Download.IsActive = 1)
ORDER BY 
    Updates.FileInfo.FileInfoId DESC
```

I am getting this message when I go to save:

[image]

I'm not sure I understand what it means by `in the query itself`. The order by is in the query so why is it issuing this message?

I am trying to get the downloads in order of the FileInfoId descending. It seems to be working but I don't want a problem down the road if I am doing this incorrectly.

Thanks!

Comment: It means when you query the view the order isn't guaranteed unless you use order by there also.

Comment: @JacobH Use the order by where? It's already in the query. I guess I'm just not understanding where it wants the order by at.

Comment: The query that uses the view. Like `select * from [view] order by...`

Comment: You're trying to hard code an order-by in a view, which ... isn't something you should be trying to do.  The ORDER BY goes in the SELECT that USES the View. You should remove this TOP 100 PERCENT and ORDER BY completely, as they violate the whole purpose of defining views.  Then use whatever ORDER BY you want or need on the actual SELECT statement that uses the View.

Comment: Recommend reviewing this thread, the accepted answer, and the linked threads in the comments of the accepted answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66353/why-is-the-order-by-clause-in-a-view-ignored-as-soon-as-its-called-with-a-where

Comment: @pmbAustin Ah, ok. Now I get it. That's what I needed to know. Thank you for the clarity. If you make this your answer, I'll upvote it.

Comment: To be clear: *A View is Not a Query, it is a Query Expression*, they are different things.

Comment: @ErocM Done, as you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to hard code an order-by in a view, which ... isn't something you should be trying to do. The ORDER BY goes in the SELECT that USES the View. You should remove this TOP 100 PERCENT and ORDER BY completely, as they violate the whole purpose of defining views. Then use whatever ORDER BY you want or need on the actual SELECT statement that uses the View.

Answer (score 1):

Its not an `Error`, it is a `Warning`, and it very clearly states what the issue is.

If you clicked <kbd>Ok</kbd> , it will create the view for you.

You have used `TOP 100 PERCENT` clause to get around the limitation of `ORDER BY` in the view definition, yet it is not guaranteed that the result will be ordered as expected if you do not use `Order By` when selecting from the view.

To keep things simple and efficient (eliminating unnecessary Order by) , take out the `Order By` and `TOP 100 PERCENT` from your view's definition and use `Order By` when selecting data from the view.

Comment: 'very clearly' to one person is not always very clear to another. I What pmbAustin said makes sense now that it was explained to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a warning message only. Remove the TOP / ORDER BY if you want to skip the warning message.